# Realm Database locale support

Tags: xamarin, internationalization, realm, locale, culture

I am investigating the internationalisation of my Xamarin mobile application. We use Realm as the local storage.

Does anyone know the status of the locale support in Realm, or of any limitations in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use resx files for localization. This is the documentation link where you can find some samples.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows

other option could be using json files for each language that you want to support.

You can use IMarkupExtension to set the key in the xaml and with the IMarkupExtension class return the correct value depending your device language.

```
     Text="{locale:YourLocalizationMarkupExtension Name}"
```

Comment: The reason for asking is that if the only locale language it supports affects the ability to search against data stored in the database. I'm assuming the searching would only work for some languages

Comment: Well that you can do Its to add a field in your realm database with the language o region "en_US", "es_ES", you can get the language and region from your devices and search in the database for the data that has this value.